# Sending values from one activity to another Activity

Tags: android

Please Read completely.
I am having four activities like 
Login,
Registration,
pendingList,
DeliveryList

I want to send userId to delivery list, but here I am not directly going from Login Activity to DeliveryList Activity. I going to the Login to PendingList.
but when the user clicks on DeliveryList on he needs userId to be present in the deliveryList. I don't even sure I am asking the question correctly, but this is my requirement. Can some one help me with an example?

Comment: Can you post the code for all of your classes involved?

Comment: Store the value inside the `SharedPreferences` and retrieve it from there.

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` or `sqLite Databae` or use `static class`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Intent` class. You can find all the specifications [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Can we use the `Intent` to send the value to all activities at a time?

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't use Shared Pref **OR** Intents to send user information from class to class. I would HIGHLY recommend using a database service like Firebase or Parse-Server. You need to carry a session for the user....then, and only then, would you be able to carry PROPER information over from activity to activity.

Look into Firebase -> it works very well for all platforms (I use Parse -> I like it better). after you get that information coded on your end, then post more questions from that stand point.

Please do not use Shared Pref, Intents, or static classes for user information.